# Separating Real and Imaginary parts from a list of solutions

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I've been asked to solve:

```
x^6 + 6 x^5 + 18 x^4 + 32 x^3 + 37 x^2 + 26 x + 11 = 0
```

This was fine and I got a list of solutions for `x`. However, now I need to convert my solutions into pairs consisting of the real and imaginary parts of `x`.

How do I do this? I've already tried creating a function

```
complexf[z_]:={Re[z],Im[z]}
```

but this won't work with my list of solutions. Any advice?

Comment: Nasser's solution is the correct way to do this, but for your edification also look up [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html). These both iterate over lists. There is also the attribute [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) which makes your function automatically iterate over lists. If you're struggling with the `->` in the solutions look up [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) which Nasser uses as `/.`.

Answer (score 2):

One way might be

```
eq=x^6+6 x^5+18 x^4+32 x^3+37 x^2+26 x+11==0;
sol=x/.Solve[eq,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ReIm[N[sol]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I just briefly sketch the solution. Since you know the polynomial is solvable, we can try to decompose it:

```
{p1[x_], p2[x_]} = 
 Decompose[x^6 + 6 x^5 + 18 x^4 + 32 x^3 + 37 x^2 + 26 x + 11, x]
(*{11 + 13 x + 6 x^2 + x^3, 2 x + x^2}*)
```

Verify:

```
p1[p2[x]] // Simplify
```

is equal to the original polynomial. Now solve p1:

```
sol1 = x /. Solve[p1[x] == 0]
```

It is advantageous that the solutions:

```
(*{-2 - (2/(3 (-9 + Sqrt[93])))^(1/3) + (1/2 (-9 + Sqrt[93]))^(1/3)/3^(2/3), 
-2 - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (1/2 (-9 + Sqrt[93]))^(1/3))/(2 3^(2/3)) + (1 - I Sqrt[3])/(2^(2/3) (3 (-9 + Sqrt[93]))^(1/3)), 
-2 - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (1/2 (-9 + Sqrt[93]))^(1/3))/(2 3^(2/3)) + (1 + I Sqrt[3])/(2^(2/3) (3 (-9 + Sqrt[93]))^(1/3))}*)
```

have easily separable real and imaginary parts. Since the second polynomial is quadratic, it represent no difficulties to solve it and find real and imaginary parts of the solutions in a closed form.